# VS C++ Header files in production build output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I'm relearning C++ after many years of higher-level languages. I've been googling around in circles for a while now on this. One issue with googling for answers in C++... "how do I include .h in my build output" just returns a bunch of results on how the #include statement works (not quite what I was looking for google... thanks...).

In visual studio, when I run a build, the output folder contains

> mydll.dll
>
> mydll.tlb
>
> mydll.xml

I know header files are required to import the DLL into another application, but I'm not sure on the process.

Do I just copy/paste the .h files into the output folder? What's the canonical way to automate this process in VS?

Is there some step I should be taking that adds them to the output?

Should I really be shipping it with multiple .h files, or is there some way I'm supposed to combine them into one large mydll.h file?

Am I correct in my understanding that .lib is only generated if something in my library is static?

Is there a good guide for creating a production build somewhere out there?

I appreciate the advice!

Comment: ***Should I really be shipping it with multiple .h files, or is there some way I'm supposed to combine them into one large mydll.h file?*** Depends on your project. if it makes sense to combine them combine them.

Comment: @drescherjm by hand, or is there some tool I should use?

Comment: ***Do I just copy/paste the .h files into the output folder?*** Long ago I used to use post build steps and an installer. However for the last 8+ years I just have CMake automate the process for me.

Comment: Probably by hand. Although you could just combine the files in your sources 
 that you use to build the dll if that makes sense to do. I have seen projects do it both ways. For example a large project like boost does not make any attempt to combine header files since it does not make sense to do so.

Comment: You need the header files to build an app that uses the dll, but you don't need them in the runtime package.

Comment: You may need header files for the interfaces that you export from your dll. With that said if your project has a `mydll.tlb` file you probably don't.

Comment: Just learn CMake. It totally worth it.

Comment: @Ivan will do! thanks.